# How to show progress of file download in native browser download bar in js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, browser, download

I am downloading a file and it shows in download bar once it is fully downloaded.
I want to show file download progress in native browser download bar that defines how many bytes get downloaded and remaining time in the download bar. Through this it will be easier for user to understand the download start otherwise there will be confusion of not downloading the file.
I tried below code but it shows only when file gets fully download. Hence not showing the progress.

```
    axios({
        url: blobUri,
        onDownloadProgress(progress) {
            console.log('download progress:', progress);
        },
    }).then(response => {
        const file = new Blob([response.data]);
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = blobUri;
        a.download = `test.pdf`;
        a.click();
        console.log('response has arrived');
    });
};
```

Comment: The problem is that the browser doesn't show progress downloading the file? This is probably an issue with the backend or the file itself. There should be a response header set that includes the size of the file and that's how the browser will determine the progress. I don't think it's possible to do this via Javascript. Can you provide a link to the file that is being downloaded?

Comment: @nevada_scout I tried to download it from azure blob storage directly to the browser download now the issue is I can't set custom name to the downloaded file.Do you know any way to set custom name to the file downloaded through bloburl?